# Should I use library CameraView of Natario1 or Fotoapparat for using camera in Android?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

I'm making a library using Camera. Currently, I am using both Camera2 and Camera API. However, I had problems with special devices of Samsung, Huawei, Xiaomi, Oppo, ... and some API versions. I really bothered about that. I searched the library online, I found the [Camera view of natario1](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) and [Fotoapparat](https://github.com/RedApparat/Fotoapparat) really good.

I would like an advice, should I use which of the two libraries to best suit all devices. Do not use AndroidX because I need to support API 14 or 15 and above. Or should I just use Camera API to make things easier. Thanks very much !

Note: My biggest priority is smooth operation on all devices. :D

Comment: If your requirements are fully satisfied with the deprecated Camera API, you can just use it for all devices.

Comment: And it will work stable on all devices?

Comment: Well, until today I have not seen devices that don't work reliably with the old API. The problem is, this API is very limited compared to **camera2**, and may be less performant in some scenarios.

Comment: I just capture, crop and preview image. With camera2, the devices work not the same. I hope old camera api will suit with all devices in the world :D

Comment: *"I hope old camera api will suit with all devices in the world"* – that's a reasonable expectation in the short run, IMHO. I don't see Google eclipsing this API abruptly. It took them about couple of years to enforce that all apps must run 64-bit, so you have an example of a timeframe for such breaking changes in Android.

Comment: Yes, I really want to use camera2 api because it took me a lot of time to learn it. But I will use the api camera if it really doesn't cause any errors. Thank Alex ^^

Comment: One warning: while it's usually OK to use **camera2** on devices with LEGACY level, you may find that there, **camera2** introduces extra overhead, and sometimes even extra bugs. You get best performance if you work trhough the deprecated Camera API for LEGACY devices, and through the camera2 API for other devices. *I know it's painful to support two versions of your code, but when you need to utilize the device in the best way, you have to pay this price.

Comment: this is my problem. Therefore, i want to find a camera library like cameraview, camerakit,.... It'll help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

### CAMERA2 API

As you have mentioned , you need support for all the devices .Before camea2 API ,google limits the level of implementation of API in different phones
But with  camera2 API , every device is given full access to all features of the API .

There are four different stage of implementation of this API . 
**LEGACY** All the feature of camera1 API will be available. No support for camera2 API. **FULL**  ALl the basic features of camer2API will be available . 
**Level 3**Some of the extra features like RAW capture are availble .
**Limites**Some basic features of camer2API will be available .

With the above four , you can check if your phone will support camera2APi or not .

Camera2 API seem to be more stable than camera1 API.

Android 5.0 and later includes Camera API2. Devices running Android 5.0 and later may not support all Camera API2 features.

Samsung, HTC, Lenovo, LG,N OnePlus have all came out with their Full supported Camera 2 API models.

With Camera 2 API, Google gives camera developers options to do more with the camera. Control the shutter speed(ISO), focus, RAW capture etc.

Comment: Thanks for big advance. Have you ever used any camera api library like CameraKit, CameraView ?

Comment: I have used camerKit in one of my project .

Comment: I have a question. Can CameraAPI handle focus touch events ?